# How to return from function when resource response is received? Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function calling an angular resource, to retrieve an item. I want the function to return the value received in the response. Anyway,

```
function getTemplate (templateId) {
    var Tx;
            Template.getTemplate({id:templateId})
                .$promise.then(
                  //success
                  function( response ){
                        Tx = response.response;
                        console.log (Tx);
                  },
                  //error
                  function( error ){
                    Tx = false;
                  }
               );
        return Tx
        }
```

When calling `Template.getTemplate(123);` I receive undefined, but I should get the response or false;

Comment: you have not defined Tx you are assigning Tx inside then callback operation which is async operation so your Tx will immediately return from function which is undefined at time of return instead you should return promise instead.

Comment: is there a way to return a promise or how should I wait for the response?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refactor your code as below it may not be exact code but will help you

```
function getTemplate (templateId,$q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer()
            Template.getTemplate({id:templateId})
                .$promise.then(
                  //success
                  function( response ){
                       deferred.resolve(response);
                  },
                  //error
                  function( error ){
                    deferred.fail("error");
                  }
               );
         return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Comment: I tried this and $promise is undefined. I'm having angular 1.1.5. I read something that $promise in resources in available since 1.1.3.

Comment: could you please set up a fiddle or plunker of your complete code

Comment: I read a bit more and $resource (in my case Template.get) doesn't return a promise, so then () can't be use.

Comment: kindly see update fiddle you should approach this problem like this way  http://jsfiddle.net/JEnQW/5/   and your resource is returning http 302 so im not getting success so it is going to error condition